# General Method For Recurrent Relations To General Formula

Tags: recurrence-relations

There's a famous problem "How many regions n lines could make at most in euclidean plane?"

I solved it into below recurrent relation:

$r_n = 2(r_{n-1} - _{n-1}\mathbf C_2) + _{n-1}\mathbf C_2$

embeded intuition in above relation is simple.

Line makes 2 regions when meets one region.

however there's some region that my additional line doesn't meet :

which are they? the answer is the combinations of each line that my additional line has already met.

That's it.

But my problem is.. I don't know how to make this recurrence into formula.

I thought if the coefficient of each $r_n$, $r_{n-1}$ is different it's impossible, however, there's already exsiting formula for this region division.

Any theoretical ground about how to formularize the recurrence relation?

Comment: There is an article in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) that discusses this.

Comment: @RossMillikan could you specify which content do I have to look to solve above given recurrence relation?

Comment: It is an in homogeneous linear recurrence.

Comment: @RossMillikan isn't it non-homgeneous since there exist n-1C2 at the right side if I move every $r_n$ to left side

Comment: Yes, the autocorrect put a space in for me.